# SAX Parser ignoring parent elements? Same named elements grouped as a result

Tags: java, android, sax, saxparser

I'm not if this is just how SAX Parser is supposed to work or if I am missing something.

This is the sort of XML I am pulling down from my server:

```
<Data>
    <Item id="1">
        <Group>
          <Name>Question One</Name>
          <type>true</type>

          <Selection>
              <Name>Answer 1</Name>
          </Selection>
        </Group>
    </Item>
    <Item id="2">
        <Group>
          <Name>Question Two</Name>
          <type>true</type>

          <Selection>
              <Name>Answer 2</Name>
          </Selection>
        </Group>
    </Item>
</Data>
```

As you can see, there is an element called "Name" that is showing up twice under different parents, containing different data. I am trying to collect "Question One" and "Question Two" in an ArrayList where I have a getter and setter of setName getName. As the title suggest my result means even the Answers are being collected into the ArrayList for that type.

Is there a way to only pull "Name" that refers to Question One and Question Two? Here is how I have it now in my end element:

```
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
        dataItem.setName(currentValue);
    }
```

Obviously I'm only looking for name, but when I've tried it for "group" then put a second if state inside I have not had any luck either. It's essentially ignoring the parents, group and selection and just collecting everything called name. Using `localName` also does not help.

I would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAX pays no attention to the hierarchy, but you can compensate for it in your code.

The `startElement`, `characters` and `endElement` methods are called appropriately on each start tag, character content and end tag in the order that they appear, so what you want to do is recognize the `<Selection>` tag in your `startElement` and set a flag in your handler to remember to ignore any `<name>` tags that occur until you unset the flag on hitting the `</Selection>` tag and recognizing it in your `endElement` method.

If you post a bit more of your `ContentHandler` code, I could probably suggest specific changes.

Comment: In the end I got my server guy to change the element name but of course your point is valid and is the way to do it if the XML cannot be changed.